# Real Time stream android device to Windows 8.1 Bootcamp

Tags: java, android, windows-8.1, miracast

I have a Nexus 5 (not rooted) which I want to mirror on Windows 8.1 running on bootcamp on my macbook pro at a high frame rate. Does anyone know of anyway of doing this?

I found http://www.airserver.com/ but it is not compatible with windows installed on a mac.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question. Maybe some Windows user forum would be a better place?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/), it mirrors via ADB.

Comment: Frame rate may be your limiter here though.

Comment: Yes I gave this a go and it was very slow.